# Why doesn't @event.users.size work?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Trying to get to total number of users for a given event and I'm thinking what I've got should work, but I get the following:

Could not find the source association(s) :squads_users in model Squad.  Try 'has_many :users, :through => :squads, :source => '.  Is it one of :team, :event, :event_division, :users, :point_adjustments, :checkpoint_squads, :division, or :checkpoints?

My ActiveRecord Kung Fu is weak :-/

**Event**

```
has_many :squads
has_many :users, :through => :squads
```

**Team**

```
 has_many :squads
```

**Squad**

```
 belongs_to :event
 belongs_to :team
 has_and_belongs_to_many :users
```

**SquadsUsers**

```
 belongs_to :user
 belongs_to :squad
```

**User**

```
 has_and_belongs_to_many :squads
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is your join model really named SquadsUsers? That might be the problem. It should be SquadUser.

Also, I think you want a many-to-many relationship between Event and Team, not Event and Squad, correct? In which case you need this:

```
Event
has_many :event_teams
has_many :teams, :through => :event_teams

EventTeam
belongs_to :event
belongs_to :team

Team
has_many :squads

Squad
belongs_to :team
has_many :squad_users
has_many :users, :through => :squad_users

SquadUser
belongs_to :squad
belongs_to :user

User
has_many :squads
```

Comment: A Team can send more than one Squad to an Event...which is why I set up the association between Events and Teams through Squads.

Comment: I've been tinkering with this for a while and not making any progress. Does my explanation for why I'm joining Teams to Events through Squads make sense?

Comment: I got it!!!! The problem was that I have an event_id column in my squad model. So in my event model when I said has_many :users, :through => :squad I had to specify the source...in this case :squad_users.

Answer (score 0):

You should remove your SquadsUsers model and just have a table called squads_users. has_and_belongs_to_many will automatically use this table without needing the additional model.